# Some sort of URL / DNS hijacking?

Tags: networking, dns

Sorry for the poor phrasing of the title but I'm not sure what exactly I'm dealing with here.

I searched something on Google and clicked on a result which I know for sure is the correct website I wanted to visit.

Instead of being redirected to the website (a quite big Payment Service Provider, so 100% legit) I was redirected to a fake Google website claiming that my IP has been chosen for a reward for my Google membership (screenshot below). My ISP and my City were also mentioned in the text, but that's not all too hard to derive from the IP I guess.

I could not reprocuce this behaviour and the fake website is not reachable anymore (it was for only 10 minutes or so).

I've seen something like this a few times before on mobile but I always thought that it was just a typo or something. But this was the first time this happened on my desktop machine (latest Firefox, Ubuntu 18.04, powerline-wired home network).

What exactly is this and how does that happen? Should I be worried?

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: [related](https://superuser.com/q/784891/172747)

Comment: @bummi Thanks! While that looks quite interesting at first, I don't think it's related to my question. I don't have any AV or "internet security" stuff installed, my router DNS settings and firmware were the first things I checked. It was the first and only occurence and I do not have any issues with reaching websites. I actually doubt that the problem is on my end since I've also seen it on mobile on a completely different network. It just appeared once and after closing the site it's like it never happened (so everything works fine).